# Issue with piecewise functions and lists of rules

Tags: function-construction, replacement, piecewise

I have a list of data that I am connecting with a simple piecewise function. I then want to evaluate the piecewise function at a different list of points. I can do it the long way, but I am wondering why the shortcuts don't work.

Function to make my piecewise:

```
f[x_, data_] := 
 Piecewise[
   Table[{data[[i - 1, 
         2]] + (x - 
          data[[i - 1, 1]]) (data[[i - 1, 2]] - 
           data[[i, 2]])/(data[[i - 1, 1]] - data[[i, 1]]) // Expand, 
     data[[i - 1, 1]] <= x <= data[[i, 1]]}, {i, 2, Length[data]}]] // Simplify
```

To create it using my points:

```
pw=f[x, mydata]
```

To evaluate (the long way):

```
pw /. {{x -> 30}, {x -> 40}, {x -> 50}}
```

This returns a list of values {number1,number2,number3} corresponding to the correct evaluation of the piecewise function at 30, 40, and 50.

How come these don't work?

```
threads = Thread[x -> #] & /@ {30, 40, 50}
pw /. threads *or*
pw /. {threads} *or*
pw /. {x -> {30, 40, 50}}
```

Comment: try `threads = Thread[{x -> #}] & /@ {30, 40, 50}` (just adding extra curlies around x->#)
`pw /. threads`

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I knew it had to be a curly braces problem but didn't know where to add them.